# Where does the "super" prefix come from in gravito-electromagnetism?

Tags: general-relativity, terminology, supersymmetry

From the analogy between the Weyl tensor and the Maxwell tensor, the arising subject of gravito-electromagnetism leads to the covariant construction of the super-energy density and super-Poynting vector.

I can't seem to find any information on the origin of the prefix "super" for these gravitational analogues, and I was hoping someone here would know.

My first thought was that it is related to supergravity, since the Bel-Robinson tensor (sometimes addressed as the super-energy-momentum tensor) plays a role in supergravity theories. But then again, using this as a reference for calling other quantities as super-quantities seemed a bit of a long shot.

A good summary on gravito-electromagnetism can be found here: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9704059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the terms were introduced by J. Garecki in his 1977 paper:

[The Superenergy Tensors](http://www.actaphys.uj.edu.pl/fulltext?series=Reg&vol=8&page=159).

They are not related to supergravity, nor is the 'super' related to supersymmetry.